# SQL: Batch update table based on MIN of another? Probably easy, but stuck

Tags: sql, mysql

I think this will be easy but I can't see how to do it!

I want to update the Author Table, so that the Earliest field contains the year of the earliest book.
I need to use MIN somehow but how to update them all with one query?

**BookTable (BookID, AuthorFK, Year)**

01 34 1943
02 34 1933
03 99 1910
04 62 1990
05 99 1901

**AuthorTable (AuthorID, Earliest)**

34 1933
62 1990
99 1901

EDIT: HA HA WORKS PERFECTLY THANKS FOR THE SUPERQUICK ANSWER! STACKO RULES (EXCEPT FOR THE OPENID THING)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update AuthorTable set Earliest = (select min(Year) from BookTable where BookTable.AuthorFK = AuthorTable.AuthorID)

Comment: While this does work, it is incredibly slow on large data sets. A method of doing this without a nested select (subselect) would be much quicker. Sadly, as far as I know, using GROUPS and MIN which also avoiding subselects is not something that can be done in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this with a joined subquery that has grouping, such as this:

update AuthorTable
set Earliest = bt.[Year]
From AuthorTable as At
Join
    (
    select AuthorFK, min(Year) as [Year] from Booktable
    group by AuthorFK
    ) as bt
on at.AuthorID = bt.AuthorFK